# Session Storage: how to store multiple objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, session-storage

Im trying to store multiple student objects (built from a form submission) into session storage and then eventually loop over session storage and display them on a page. Im not very familiar with any of this and its my first crack at it... 
How do i store multiple students ? i feel like i need an append... im just overwriting every time...
Thanks !

btw... must be pure JS

**HTML**

```
             <div id="infoStyle" class="col-lg-6 center-block infoWindow animated">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <h4>First Name : <input id="fName" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{50}" title="50 characters or less"></h4>
                <h4>Last Name : <input id="lName" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{50}" title="50 characters or less"></h4>
                <h4>Email Address : <input id="email" type="email"></h4>
                <br>
                <a onclick="createStudent()" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Create Student</a>
                <br><br>
                <a onclick="cancel()" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Cancel</a>
             </div>
```

**JS**

```
    function createStudent(){

    var student = new Object();

    student.fName = document.getElementById('fName').value;
    student.lName = document.getElementById('lName').value;
    student.email = document.getElementById('email').value;

    sessionStorage.setItem('student', JSON.stringify(student));

    var retrievedObject = sessionStorage.getItem('student');
    console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You need to store into an `array`, but before that you will need to **check if the array student already exists** on sessionStorage or not.

2) Then add a new student to the array, and store it into localstorage

3) while you retrive the data there is no change, it correct what you have written

```
function createStudent(){


      // this is how you set it
    var newStudent = new Object();

    newStudent .fName = document.getElementById('fName').value;
    newStudent .lName = document.getElementById('lName').value;
    newStudent .email = document.getElementById('email').value;

    if(sessionStorage.student)
    {
     student= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('student'));
    }else{
     student=[];
    }
    student.push(newStudent )
    sessionStorage.setItem('student', JSON.stringify(student));

       // this is how you will retrive it

    var retrievedObject = sessionStorage.getItem('student');
    console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));

}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gawjgjto/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the response... im breaking on 

student.push(newStudent )

ive been up a long time... what am i missing lol

Comment: let me create a fiddle for you

Comment: thanks man !!!! I actually was messing with an array earlier thinking that was the way to go.... just wasnt sure.

Comment: @JayD.. you can create a fiddle and try to show me where it goes wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71252/discussion-between-jayd-and-naeem-shaikh).

Answer (score -1):

working...

```
    function createStudent(){

    var newStudent = new Object();

    newStudent.fName = document.getElementById('fName').value;
    newStudent.lName = document.getElementById('lName').value;
    newStudent.email = document.getElementById('email').value;

    if(sessionStorage.student)
    {
     student= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('student'));
    }else{
     student=[];
    }
 student.push(newStudent )   
    console.log(student);
    sessionStorage.setItem('student', JSON.stringify(student));

    var retrievedObject = sessionStorage.getItem('student');
    console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));


}
```